# Resources for Exam 70-573

Tags: 2010

Does anyone know a good company that offers software for trying questions for this exams? I usually buy selftestsoftware.com or measureup.com but this exam is very new and they dont have it yet.

Any other else?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luis - The official classroom course is available for this now.  It does a fair job of preparing one for the exam, but not a great job in my opinion.  http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-573

What I found helpful was to go through the required skills on this page http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-573#tab2 and create my own study guide  using the SharePoint 2010 SDK for reference.

It takes a little more time to prepare, but in doing so I felt like I learned better than I would have by studying sample questions.

Also, I haven't seen any other sites that offer sample questions yet.

Good luck!

Comment: If you can get exam insurance, I would also reccommend taking the exam even when you are not 100%.  You will get a better feel for the type of questions and a high-level breakdown of your strong/weak areas.  Who knows, you may even surprise yourself and pass!

Answer (score 0):

[SharPoint2010 Exam Guide](http://spserver2010.blogspot.com/2010/09/sharepoint-2010-developer-exam-70-573.html)

Comment: Thanks ! I am studying it atm and writing my own guide. Your links are useful.